# Office 365 and local Lync for PBX

Tags: lync, microsoft-office-365

I have Office 365 E1 plan to get Exchange and Lync.

Now we want to be able to call the landlines with Lync. I suppose I need to setup a local Lync server for this?

We only have one public IP, so I'm actually worried that this setup will require additional SSL certificates, as we've used the public IP once already for AD FS?

I've searched for a while now but I can't find a good walkthrough of this setup. Has anyone done this? How was the experience?

Answer (score 3):

You will need an on-premise Lync deployment to get the functionality you are after. In Lync this feature is called Enterprise voice.

There are a number of ways to connect the Lync environment to the PSTN the 2 most commons are:

1. Use a TDM/IP gateway to connect to an existing ISDN circuit.
2. SIP trunk over MPLS (you can get them over the internet but the quality is generally poor).

Best place to start is the MS Lync documentation:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg398616.aspx
It has a section dedicated to planning Enterprise voice.

With regards to the public IP address, shouldn't be a problem for the Enterprise voice features. It will be a problem if you want to deploy either Federation or remote user access.

Implementing Enterprise voice is a non-trivial exercise, I'd recommend finding a MS approved partner (list here:http://lync.microsoft.com/en-us/Partners/Pages/lync-partner-finder.aspx)